# Strip out debug activities from production APK

Tags: android, debugging

I know in latest version on Android tools we can use if (BuildConfig.DEBUG == true) which I believe it will strip out the code.

Is it possible to strip out activities that are only used for debugging purposes from the production release APK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to strip out activities that are only used for debugging purposes from the production release APK?

From a Java standpoint, ProGuard could probably get rid of them, with the appropriate rules. However, the manifest entries would remain, as would any resources that only those development-mode-only activities would need, etc. At best, this will increase bloat. At worst, if the manifest entries have exported these activities (e.g., via publishing an `<intent-filter>`), then your app will crash when something tries to run those activities.

Comment: That's what I thought also. I am OK with some bloat in the manifest, as long as someone tries to use am start <intent> and my app crashes then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such feature. You could probably try to do that having custom build scripts, but maybe it would suffice to simply check `debuggable` flag of the app:

```
Boolean isDebuggable = ((getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0);
```